# Stop setTImeout() function to refresh countdown

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript countdown function which works fine. but I got no clue to stop and refresh the timer to extend the time.
When I call this function again before timeout, it works very strange. It shows two countdown time because updateTimer() function is still working. So I surfed the net and found clearTimeout() function to stop this countdown. But I don't know to how apply to this function.

Please help me to stop and refresh this timer.

```
function countdown(elementName, minutes, seconds) {
    var element, endTime, hours, mins, msLeft, time;


    function twoDigits(n) {
        return (n <= 9 ? "0" + n : n);
    }

    function updateTimer() {
        msLeft = endTime - (+new Date);
        if (msLeft < 1000) {
            element.innerHTML = "00:00";
        } else {
            time = new Date(msLeft);
            hours = time.getUTCHours();
            mins = time.getUTCMinutes();
            element.innerHTML = twoDigits(time.getUTCMinutes()) + ':' + twoDigits(time.getUTCSeconds());
            setTimeout(updateTimer, time.getUTCMilliseconds() + 500);
        }
    }

    element = document.getElementById(elementName);
    endTime = (+new Date) + 1000 * (60 * minutes + seconds) + 500;
    updateTimer();

    return stopTimer();
}

countdown("countdown", 0, 30);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store your `setTimeout()` in a variable. Anonymous timeouts cannot be cleared.

```
var timeout;

function countdown(elementName, minutes, seconds) {
    var element, endTime, hours, mins, msLeft, time;


    function twoDigits(n) {
        return (n <= 9 ? "0" + n : n);
    }

    function updateTimer() {
        msLeft = endTime - (+new Date);
        if (msLeft < 1000) {
            element.innerHTML = "00:00";
        } else {
            time = new Date(msLeft);
            hours = time.getUTCHours();
            mins = time.getUTCMinutes();
            element.innerHTML = twoDigits(time.getUTCMinutes()) + ':' + twoDigits(time.getUTCSeconds());
            timeout = setTimeout(updateTimer, time.getUTCMilliseconds() + 500);
        }
    }

    element = document.getElementById(elementName);
    endTime = (+new Date) + 1000 * (60 * minutes + seconds) + 500;
    updateTimer();

    stopTimer();
}

function stopTimer() {
  clearTimeout(timeout);
}

countdown("countdown", 0, 30);
```

Comment: Oh.. Thanks.. .. Can I put stopTimer() into the function countdown() as a sub function?

Comment: Yes surely you can. One more thing: you do not need `return`. Just call the function directly.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set a global variable equal to the returned value of `setTimeout(...)`, and then pass this global variable into the `clearTimeout()` func.

Here's how:

```
let tm;


function countdown(elementName, minutes, seconds) {
    var element, endTime, hours, mins, msLeft, time;
    


    function twoDigits(n) {
        return (n <= 9 ? "0" + n : n);
    }

    function stopTimer(t) {
        return clearTimeout(t);
    }

    function updateTimer() {
        msLeft = endTime - (+new Date);
        if (msLeft < 1000) {
            element.innerHTML = "00:00";
        } else {
            time = new Date(msLeft);
            hours = time.getUTCHours();
            mins = time.getUTCMinutes();
            element.innerHTML = twoDigits(time.getUTCMinutes()) + ':' + twoDigits(time.getUTCSeconds());
            tm = setTimeout(updateTimer, time.getUTCMilliseconds() + 500);
        }
    }

    element = document.getElementById(elementName);
    endTime = (+new Date) + 1000 * (60 * minutes + seconds) + 500;
    updateTimer();

    return stopTimer(tm);
}

countdown("countdown", 0, 30);
```